# How to interactively create an edge on canvas between two nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

As in the cytoscape.js to make an interactive communication between nodes? Is it possible? In similarity how it is implemented in a factoid (http://webservice.baderlab.org:3000/).

That is, you can interactively create an edge on canvas between two nodes and then save it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The bundled edgehandles plugin is what you're looking for, though you'll also need the cxtmenu plugin or some other manual UI for starting the gesture (e.g. a mode + tap) to support touch devices.  They have their options documented at the top of the source, and they will be further documented in 2.1 once they are migrated to the jQuery plugin site -- those plugins are simply jQuery plugins that use the cy.js API afterall.